# How to get soft keyboard auto-correct suggestions?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

Is there a way to access the soft keyboard's auto-correct suggestions?

I have dug around [in Handling Keyboard Input](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/index.html) and [in the InputMethodManager api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html), which has led me to the [CorrectionInfo class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/CorrectionInfo.html).  I am not sure where to start though with accessing this CorrectionInfo.  Any help and tips are appreciated!

(**Note:** I am looking to directly access the keyboard's suggestions, I do not want to make suggestions of my own, nor do I want the input I receive to be auto-corrected for me)

Comment: so you need this:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/BaseInputConnection.html#commitCorrection(android.view.inputmethod.CorrectionInfo) ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for - it sounds more like that is used to commit a correction, whereas I am interested in finding out the possible corrections for a given character sequence the user has typed

Comment: what about this: InputMethodService#onDisplayCompletions ?

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion, but this one appears to be used by an application to display auto-completion candidates.  I am looking for the auto-correct candidates provided by the keyboard

Comment: ok,  so i assume its your keyboard? or std or third party keyboard ?

Comment: Its a standard softinput keyboard for Android that is displayed when an EditText is focused

Comment: hmm,  then what you want is imho mission impossible

Comment: I have implemented my own keyboard. With that in mind, is it possible to get possible corrections for a given character sequence (based on current chosen language for the keyboard)? So I don't have to reinvent the wheel?